# Blank screen randomly rendered when opening html file in app on iOS after closing app

Tags: flutter

I have an app that displays html files that are being opened in email client. I am using MethodChannel to send send data from MainActivity/AppDelegate to main.dart, save the file to storage and open in it webview. My main.dart is here https://github.com/akravets/sandbox/blob/master/main.dart.

The html files are quite big - 20 to 30 MB. As I open attachments, everything is ok, but after I close my app and try to open an attachment, I get a blank screen. I can open another file after that, but that first open after closing app always fails.

Relevant code could be here:

```
    String fileName = data.substring(0, indexOfSeparator);
    String content = data.substring(indexOfSeparator + 3);

    if (_fileName != fileName) {
      setState(() {
        _fileName = fileName;
        writeLog("Setting fileName in state: $fileName");
      });
    }

    final file = await _localFile(fileName);

    writeData(file, content).then((f) {
     writeLog("File write OK, reloading webView with file ${file.path}");
     flutterWebviewPlugin.reloadUrl('file://${file.path}');
   }
```

Any ideas what could be the issue here?

Comment: Are you tried to use `flutterWebviewPlugin.launch()` instead `flutterWebviewPlugin.reloadUrl()`

Comment: Yes, same behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that I was setting state and calling flutterWebviewPlugin.reloadUrl('file://${file.path}'); after that. What I suspect was happening is that state would change, build would be called, but reloading of webView would not happen correctly - there was timing issue. What solved the problem was changing state in webView's listener, so that build would be triggered after all the data was ready

```
 flutterWebviewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) {
    setState(() {
      _fileName = fileName;
      writeLog("Setting fileName in state: $fileName");
    });
  });
```